# IE6 anchor click moves the iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

We are facing a weird problem in IE6. The page works fine in Firefox and IE7.

We have a page which has a div and a iframe within that div
Example:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div>
   <iframe src="page.aspx" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now assume page.aspx has this code:

```
<html>
<body>
..
 <a href="#" onclick="alert('just an alert');">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if user clicks on the link 'click me' then the iframe moves!
Here is a depiction of the behavior:

**Before clicking on the link**

[image]

**After clicking on the link**

[image]

It seems like none of the code written by us is causing an issue, as the only thing that happens when the user clicks on the link 'click me' is to just show an alert box.

has anybody faced a similar issue? Any pointers about how to resolve this problem?

PS: It is difficult for me to reproduce the problem with a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add a `return false;`? It's needed to avoid the default behavior of the anchor.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('just an alert');return false;">click me</a>
```

Comment: fantastic! you have no idea how helpful your post was :-) ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if we add width property to the iframe the problem disaapears

Comment: Not for me. The crazy thing is that depends on which link I click. I have a menu with anchors and I managed onClick() on each anchor for loading the `iframe` with that url. Just one url is moving the `iframe` to the top left of the page. So, I suspect if the HTML loaded in the `iframe` has something to do with it.

Comment: My suspicious were right. I've checked the source code of the page that was getting problems. The page that moved the `iframe` to the top left of my page has a script that maximizes the window. Any ideas how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could put up a very simple demo of this that on the public web somewhere.  If you did that we could play around with it a little and see what's up.

Comment: It is difficult for me to reproduce the problem with a simple example.

Comment: well i can't comment on your solution (I don't have enough points) but I'm glad you solved it.